# in PHP to call one form so many times depending upon specific value

Tags: php

I am now developing a travel agency website, in this site when the user reserves a trip he/she have to enter trip related details. This information is collected in a forma. The user also enters the number of people who are travelling.

My question is, how do I gather the same information for everyone who is travelling? Basically I need the form to be generated for the number of people that are travelling so I can capture all their data. How do I do this?

Comment: You will need to add some specific information about where you are stuck - possibly show some code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfPeople; $i++) : ?>
    Person <?php echo $i + 1; ?>
    <input name="person[<?php echo $i; ?>][name]" type="text">
    <input name="person[<?php echo $i; ?>][age]" type="text">
    .
    .
    .
<?php endfor; ?>
```

The use `foreach ($_POST['person'] as $person)` to go through the entered details...

Answer (score 0):

beware psevdo-code:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="num" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset ($_POST['num'])) {
  for ($i = 0; $i > $_POST['num']; $i++) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="ppl' . $i . '" /><br />';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I hade wrote it like what you told me ; but when I view the content of the form ,it disappear I don't know why , I will show you my form

Comment: <form action = "insertpassenger.php" method = "POST">
 <center>Enter all the information below</center>
<?php for ($i=0;$i<$pplno;$i++) : ?>
peopke<?php echo $i+1 ; ?>
<input type="text" name="cpr" size="9" value="<?php echo $cpr;?>" maxlength="9">CPR
<input type="text" name="pplno" size="30" maxlength="25">Number Of People
<input type="text" name="gcpr" size="9" maxlength="9">dad CPR
<input type="reset" value="clear" name="clear">
<input type="submit" value="join" name="join">
<?php endfor; ?> 
</form>

Comment: `<form action = "insertpassenger.php" method = "POST">

 <center>Enter all the information below</center>

<?php for ($i=0;$i<$pplno;$i++) : ?>

people<?php echo $i+1 ; ?>

<input type="text" name="cpr" size="9" value="<?php echo $cpr;?>" maxlength="9">CPR

<input type="text" name="pplno" size="30" maxlength="25">Number Of People

<input type="text" name="gcpr" size="9" maxlength="9">dad CPR

<input type="reset" value="clear" name="clear">
<input type="submit" value="join" name="join">

<?php endfor; ?> 

</form>`

Comment: sorry I don't know how to make it like A php code; to see the code much clearly;;thnxx alot for your attention